# how to mesaure useCallback and useMemo performance

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to convert all my legacy codes into functional components.

While I'm doing this, It seems there are some performance issues I couldn't see when I was in class component.

One of my attempt dealing with this was useCallback, but I hope to see exactly how this hook affects my performance.

Is there any way to measure how `useCallback` or `useMemo` improved my codes?

Comment: not sure if there is a clear way to measure except counting renders with `console.log` but you can checkout this article https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback